# T-SQL : selecting multiple columns with distinct value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to select distinct reservation dates over the count of reservation dates for each date. I need to compare the license key from the `reservation date` table to `LicenseKeyTB`.

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT 
  l.LicenseKey,
  numOfReservation
FROM 
  RX.LicenseKeyTB l 
  JOIN (
    SELECT  
      r.LicenseKey,
      DISTINCT r.ReservationDate,  
      COUNT(r.ReservationDate)
        OVER (PARTITION BY r.ReservationDate ORDER BY r.LicenseKey) as numOfRes
    FROM 
      RX.ReservationTB r
  ) AS ReservatonDateCount
    ON ReservatonDateCount.LicenseKey = l.LicenseKey;
```

[sql diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYWwT.png)

I am getting the following error:

> Column 'RX.ReservationTB.LicenseKey' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

EDIT --------------

Sorry I didn't give the whole picture. What I am trying to do is to check if a license key is available for a certain range of dates. For the range of dates I cannot go over the number of total seats I have for the license key**s**. There's a license key for Office 2010 and there's another one for Office 2013. For both license keys there's a total number of seats available. I cannot go over the alloted number of seats. e.g. I cannot have 5 Office 2010 and 8 Office 2013 licenses checked out at once but I can have 4 and 6.

I need to query for a license key for product(e.g. Office 2010) where the total number of reservations for the date range do not go above the number of total seats available for both license keys.

I need to check the corresponding license key if the range of reservation dates reaches total number of seats.

[complete sql diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYWwT.png)

Breaking this up:

First thing I need to do is see how many reservations I have for a given range per a license key.

```
-- number of reservations per day for a license key
SELECT 
  l.LicenseKey,
  l.ReservationDate,
  COUNT(1) AS numOfReservation
FROM RX.ReservationTB l 
WHERE l.LicenseKey = '6RCX3-H722D-8MQT6-8Y2VC-FY9FG'
AND CONVERT(date, '20151130')<=l.ReservationDate
AND l.ReservationDate<CONVERT(date, '20151205')
GROUP BY l.LicenseKey, l.ReservationDate
ORDER BY l.LicenseKey, l.ReservationDate
```

-- Not I need a list of product license keys that are available for the given date range.

....

Here's what I have so far:

```
SELECT
    p.Name, 
    s.SeatsTotal,
    COUNT(1) AS numOfReservation
    FROM RX.ProductTB p 
        JOIN RX.LicenseKeyTB l ON p.ProductID=l.LicenseKey
        JOIN RX.SeatsAvailableTB s ON l.SeatID=s.SeatID
        JOIN RX.ReservationTB r ON r.LicenseKey=l.LicenseKey
            WHERE CONVERT(date, '20151130')<=r.ReservationDate
                AND r.ReservationDate<CONVERT(date, '20151205')
    GROUP BY p.Name, s.SeatsTotal
```

I am getting this error message:

```
Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '6RCX3-H722D-8MQT6-8Y2VC-FY9FG' to data type int.
```

Comment: `DISTINCT` only ever applies to the **entire row** - you cannot get "distinct" column values. The syntax is `SELECT DISTINCT (list of columns)` (the `DISTINCT` keyword cannot be in the middle of the column list)

Comment: Can you supply sample data and desired results?  In addition to the misuse of `distinct`, the error you posted is because you can't use `order by` in the `partition` clause when using `count` -- nothing to order with count...

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a per-column qualifier, it is a modifier for `SELECT`.  You either `SELECT DISTINCT` or you just `SELECT` [not necessarily distinct].

Comment: In any event, I'm having trouble making sense of what you're trying to do.  It appears that in the inline view you want only one row per distinct `ReservationDate`, but it's unclear how the row should be chosen when there is more than one candidate.

Comment: Also, looking at your diagram, why is `ReservationTB.ReservationDate` a key column?  Is it really intended that there can be two rows with the same `RentalOrderNum` and different `ReservationDate`?

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure what you are trying to do here but maybe it is as simple as this?

```
SELECT r.LicenseKey
    , r.ReservationDate
    , COUNT(r.ReservationDate) as numOfRes
FROM RX.ReservationTB r
group by r.LicenseKey
    , r.ReservationDate
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you simply want `count(distinct)`:

```
SELECT r.LicenseKey,
       COUNT(DISTINCT r.ReserationDate) as numOfReservation
FROM RX.ReservationTB l 
GROUP BY r.LicenseKey;
```

Note that the join is not necessary because `LicenseKey` is in the reservations table and appears to be a foreign key reference to `LicenseTB`.

Comment: Hmm.  I'd buy "the join is not necessary because `ReservationTB.LicenseKey` is a foreign key referencing the license key table".  If not for the FK relationship, however, the join would serve to filter out rows where the reserved license key is not present in the license key table.  Of course, the given join would not be possible at all if `LicenseKey` were not in the reservations table.

Comment: @JohnBollinger . . . That is worth making explicit, so I did.

Answer (score 0):

Some questions on what you are trying to do here, but if I stay with the 2 columns you are selecting in your example I get:

```
SELECT 
  l.LicenseKey,
  COUNT(1) AS numOfReservation,
  COUNT(DISTINCT l.ReservationDate) AS DaysLicenseUsed
FROM RX.ReservationTB l 
GROUP BY l.LicenseKey
ORDER BY l.LicenseKey
```

If you are trying to get number of reservations per day for each license it would be:

```
SELECT 
  l.LicenseKey,
  l.ReservationDate,
  COUNT(1) AS numOfReservation,
FROM RX.ReservationTB l 
GROUP BY l.LicenseKey, l.ReservationDate
ORDER BY l.LicenseKey, l.ReservationDate
```